# Can't Install ovirt-engine-sdk-python from pip on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pip, lxml, ovirt

I'm trying to install the ovirt python sdk on my Windows 10 64-bit machine using the command

```
pip install ovirt-engine-sdk-python
```

and I got the following error

```
Collecting ovirt-engine-sdk-python
  Using cached ovirt-engine-sdk-python-4.4.10.tar.gz (333 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pycurl>=7.19.0 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from ovirt-engine-sdk-python) (7.43.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from ovirt-engine-sdk-python) (1.15.0)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for ovirt-engine-sdk-python, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: ovirt-engine-sdk-python
    Running setup.py install for ovirt-engine-sdk-python ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5bmup8ae\\ovirt-engine-sdk-python_e4aa3cc952084095b14b9ec184319630\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5bmup8ae\\ovirt-engine-sdk-python_e4aa3cc952084095b14b9ec184319630\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-2ivjrddy\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python37\Include\ovirt-engine-sdk-python'
         cwd: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5bmup8ae\ovirt-engine-sdk-python_e4aa3cc952084095b14b9ec184319630\
    Complete output (28 lines):
    4.4.10
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\ovirtsdk4
    copying lib\ovirtsdk4\http.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\ovirtsdk4
    copying lib\ovirtsdk4\reader.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\ovirtsdk4
    copying lib\ovirtsdk4\readers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\ovirtsdk4
    copying lib\ovirtsdk4\service.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\ovirtsdk4
    copying lib\ovirtsdk4\services.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\ovirtsdk4
    copying lib\ovirtsdk4\types.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\ovirtsdk4
    copying lib\ovirtsdk4\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\ovirtsdk4
    copying lib\ovirtsdk4\writer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\ovirtsdk4
    copying lib\ovirtsdk4\writers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\ovirtsdk4
    copying lib\ovirtsdk4\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\ovirtsdk4
    running build_ext
    building 'ovirtsdk4.xml' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\ext
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcext\ov_xml_module.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\ext\ov_xml_module.obj
    ov_xml_module.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcext\ov_xml_reader.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\ext\ov_xml_reader.obj
    ov_xml_reader.c
    ext\ov_xml_reader.c(20): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlreader.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5bmup8ae\\ovirt-engine-sdk-python_e4aa3cc952084095b14b9ec184319630\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5bmup8ae\\ovirt-engine-sdk-python_e4aa3cc952084095b14b9ec184319630\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-2ivjrddy\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python37\Include\ovirt-engine-sdk-python' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I already installed the latest c++ buildtools by using MS Visual Studio, I also already downloaded the latest libxml package but still can't install the ovirt package.

```
pip install lxml
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (4.6.3)
```

Is there something that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

From `README.adoc`:

> The SDK uses [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org) for parsing and rendering XML. The part of the SDK that interacts with that library is written in C. This means that before building you must make sure you have the C compiler and the required header and libraries files installed in your system. For example, if you are using distributions like Fedora, or CentOS:

> dnf -y install gcc libxml2-devel python3-devel

> If you are using distributions like Debian, or Ubuntu:

> apt-get --assume-yes install gcc libxml2-dev python3-dev

For w32 try one of these: http://xmlsoft.org/sources/win32/ (found in http://xmlsoft.org/downloads.html).

Comment: I already downlaoded the files but I'm not sure where to put them